# Configuring Tomcat for customized protocol handler

Tags: tomcat, protocol

This is on Tomcat 9.0.71.

I need to use a protocol handler of **com.ibm.crypto.provider**.
I set **JAVA_OPTS** with `-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=com.ibm.crypto.provider` but this is not sufficient. The problem is that **catalina.sh** contains the line:

`JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources"`

This overrides my setting of **java.protocol.handler.pkgs**.

I can update catalina.sh to achieve the desired setting - but am unhappy with that as a solution (changing the supported code). Questions:

1. What is the best method to set java.protocol.handler.pkgs
2. Should I just set java.protocol.handler.pkgs to com.ibm.crypto.provider OR should it be a concatenation with org.apache.catalina.webresources
3. If I need both packages concatenated what is the syntax for this?

thank you